# Erro array upload imagens

Tags: php, file-upload, multiple-file-upload

Consigo inserir os dados normalmente, mas o upload de imagens não funciona.
Retorna sempre o erro:

> Warning: Undefined array key "files" in
> /var/www/html/projects/rafael/controllers/productsController.php on
> line 63

```
public function add()
{
    $data = array();
    $u = new Users();
    $u->setLoggedUser();
    $company = new Companies($u->getCompany());
    $data['company_name'] = $company->getName();
    $data['user_email'] = $u->getEmail();

    if ($u->hasPermission('inventory_add')) {
        $products = new Products();

        if (isset($_POST['product_name']) && !empty($_POST['product_name'])) {
            $countfiles = count($_FILES['files']);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $countfiles; $i++) {
        
                // File name
                $filename = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
        
                // Location
                $target_file = 'upload/' . $filename;
        
                // file extension
                $file_extension = pathinfo(
                    $target_file,
                    PATHINFO_EXTENSION
                );
        
                $file_extension = strtolower($file_extension);
        
                // Valid image extension
                $valid_extension = array("png", "jpeg", "jpg");
        
                if (in_array($file_extension, $valid_extension)) {
        
                    // Upload file
                    if (move_uploaded_file(
                        $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],
                        $target_file
                    )) {
                        chmod($target_file, 0666);

                    }
                }
            }

            $product_name = addslashes($_POST['product_name']);
            $aditional_info = addslashes($_POST['aditional_info']);

            $products->add($product_name, $aditional_info, $u->getCompany());

            header("Location: " . BASE_URL . "products");
        }
        $this->loadTemplate('products_add', $data);
    } else {
        header("Location: " . BASE_URL . "unauthorized");
    }
}
```

Comment: qual seria a linha 63 na qual o erro ocorre?

Comment: É essa linha:

if (isset($_POST['product_name']) && !empty($_POST['product_name']))

Porém ai está ($_POST) e eu estou tentando fazer upload via ($_FiLES)

Comment: certo, o que está errado é a superglobal `$_FILES['files']`, ela não existe. Use um `var_dump($_FILES)` para confirmar se o `count()` vai ser feito ai mesmo.